# Problem with React Context State not Updating in real time. It only updates when i reload but not immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing an issue in my React application where the state within a React context is not updating immediately, but only after I reload the page. I think maybe it's wrong in the UPDATE case in **WorkoutsContext.jsx**

**WorkoutsContext.jsx**

```jsx
const workoutsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (
    action.type 
  ) {
..
    case "UPDATE_WORKOUT":
      return {
        workouts: state.workouts.map((w) => (w._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : w)),
      };
..
  }
};

const WorkoutContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, {
    workouts: null,
  });

  return <WorkoutsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>{children}</WorkoutsContext.Provider>;
};
```

**UpdateModal.jsx**

```jsx
const UpdateModal = ({ closeModal, initialValues }) => {
..
  const { dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
..
    const response = await fetch("api/workouts/" + initialValues.id, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedWorkout),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const json = await response.json();
..
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("workout updated");
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_WORKOUT", payload: json });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider useEffect to trigger the re-render. because the reducer is outside of the function you have to let it know when to update.